# How can I stop getting notifications about signing into my Google account?

Tags: permission, gmail, accounts, google

I've tried configuring my laptop to sync my calendar and contacts, but not my mail, with my Google account.

[image: Internet Accounts preferences screenshot]

Now I've started to get notifications asking me to log into my Google account, but when I do so, MacOS is asking for permissions related to Gmail, in addition to the expected Google Calendar and Contacts.

[image: MacOS asking for too many permissions]

These are permissions I don't want to give, especially the permission to permanently delete all of my emails.

Is this an all-or-nothing situation? Or is there a way to give MacOS only the permissions it needs to connect the services I've configured to be connected?

**UPDATE**

I tried activating ONLY contacts, yet I'm still getting asked to authorize mail, calendar and chat messages. Here's a new screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You are giving macOS the ability to sign into your Google account.  As far as Google is concerned (and it is a Google message you are seeing), that allows access to mail on Google servers as well as contacts and calendar.

But you have told macOS not to configure Apple Mail to use Google mail services. I see no reason to doubt that.

Regarding the two questions in your post:

- Yes, it is all-or-nothing from Google's perspective.
- From the Mac's perspective, you have given it the permissions to only do what you want.